# Why am I getting the error "There is already open data reader associated which must be closed first"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to make a simple accounts register page with requiredvalidator for textboxes and comparevalidator to confirm password.

the validators work fine.

When I inserted the correct data in correct format, I receive an error
" there is already open DataReader associated which must be closed first"
Why is it so? How do I fix it?

here are my c# codes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 static readonly string scriptErrorUserId =
 "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
 "alert (\"Error - Username you keyed in is taken up, please key in another Username\");\n" +
 "</script>";

static readonly string scriptSuccessNewAccount =
"<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
"alert (\"Your account has been succesfully created - Thank You!\");\n" +
"</script>";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection mDB = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=iipproject.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=IIP Project;Integrated Security=False;User ID=beatrice135;Password=Tompel1997;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");

    mDB.Open();
    Type csType = this.GetType();
    // check to ensure that UserId keyed in is not being in used by other Customers
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    string strSQLSelect = "SELECT cUsername FROM Customer ORDER BY cUsername";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read() == true)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == (string)rdr["cUsername"])
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorUserId);
            mDB.Close();
            return;
        }
    }
    // insert new record
    string strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO "
        + " Customer (cUsername, cPassword, cFirstName, cLastName, cAddress, cEmail, cPhone,cTitle,cGender,cPostalCode,cBirthDate)"
        + " VALUES (@username,@pw,@fn,@ln,@add,@email,@phone,@title,@gender,@postcode,@birthdate)";

    cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLInsert, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", txtUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", txtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", txtBirthDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", txtPostalCode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", ddlTitle.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mDB.Close();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Success", scriptSuccessNewAccount);

    // prepare Session variables for newly registered customer
    Session["sFlag"] = "T";
    Session["sUsername"] = (string)txtUsername.Text;
    Session["sFirstName"] = (string)txtFirstName.Text;
    Session["sAddress"] = (string)txtAddress.Text;
    Session["sEmail"] = (string)txtEmail.Text;
    Session["sPhone"] = (string)txtPhone.Text;
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Because `rdr` from `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` is still open and must be closed first, which the error and your research for it should have indicated.

Comment: Use the `using`-statement for everything that implements `IDisposable`, here for the connection, the `SqlCommand` and the `SqlDataReader`

Comment: Basically your DataReader rdr is accessing Customer table (DataReader is connected object to database) you can not modify the Customer table until you have closed rdr.

In your case instead DataReader use DataSet and loop through rows; things should work.

Comment: Oh dear. The right way to find out if there is a row containing a particular value in a particular column is to query the database with a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause. The *wrong* way to do it is to query the table for all rows and compare them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is self-explanatory. After reading your data you have to dispose the reader:

```
...
 while (rdr.Read() == true)
    {
        if (txtUsername.Text == (string)rdr["cUsername"])
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorUserId);
            mDB.Close();
            return;
        }
    }
rdr.Close();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. Please close the data reader after the while loop. `rdr.close();` 
However as a good practice, please use `using` statement which will take care of closing the data reader or connection.